# Having an issue in my Java program

Tags: java

the over all point of this program is "Write a program that prompts the user for an integer between 2 and 10 and prints out all integers between 1 and 100, except for the integer multiples of the number entered by the user (modulois useful).
For example, if the user entered 9, your program should print out all the numbers between 1 and 100 except for those printed by program 1." The problem I am having is the program prints the exact opposite of what I want to do! Prints all the multiples of the number entered :(
I am a student so advice and help is welcome but more than anything I would like to learn how to THINK about solving this program to help me in the future. Thanks all :)

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProgramTwo
/*
 * 
 */
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a number you would like to use: ");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int eviltwinNumb=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=eviltwinNumb; i<=100; i+=eviltwinNumb)
    {
        if(i%i != 0 )
        {
             i++;
        }

         System.out.println(+i);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What? Seriously? i%i? It will always be 0

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the loop at the number you entered, and you increment i by that number in each step, and your condition makes no difference at all (it's never true). That's why your code prints precisely the numbers you don't want to be printed (eviltwinNumb, 2*eviltwinNumb, 3*eviltwinNumb, ...).

You should increment i by just 1 in each step, and print it only if `(i%eviltwinNumb != 0 )`.

Comment: Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++)  // loop from 1 to 100
{
    if(i%eviltwinNumb != 0 )  // if not an exact multiple of eviltwinNumb 
    {
        System.out.println(i);  // print it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll explain why it's *not* working.  The loop begins by setting `i` to the entered number, and each iteration through the loop you increment `i` by the chosen number with `i += eviltwinNumb`.  Thus, you are only ever considering multiples of the given number.  Additionally, your if statement will never trigger, because i % i = 0 for all i, so it is currently useless (think about it -- any number divided by itself will always have no remainder, which is what the modulus operator (%) calculates).

Instead, you should think about how to print the numbers *other than* the multiples.  To do that, you must consider each number between 1 and 100 -- thus your for loop should iterate from `i=1` to `100`.  Then, for each number `i`, you should consider whether it is a multiple of `eviltwinNumb`.  You can do this with `i % eviltwinNumb`.  If it *is* a multiple, *don't* print it.  Or, rather, if it *isn't* a multiple, *do* print it.  Thus, you should only print `i` when `i % eviltwinNumb != 0`.

To see a complete example, see Scary Wombat's post, but hopefully this discussion helped your understanding.